# Previous week open and close in a pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

new to pine. I can get the open/close of the previous trading day no problem as follows:

openprice = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open[1])

But what I want is the previous weeks open and close. So if today is Wednesday I'm looking for the close on the previous friday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the `security()` is `tiemframe`.

> ***timeframe (simple string)*** Timeframe of the requested data. To use the chart's timeframe, use an empty string or the timeframe.period
> variable. Valid timeframe strings are documented in the User Manual's
> Timeframes page.

So, you can pass `"W"` for weekly data.

```
weekly_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", close[1])
```